# Bitwise operation exercise

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-or

I have the following exercise: The numbers n0 to n7 are bytes represented in binary system. The task is every bit to drop either to the bottom or if it meets another bit it stays above it. Here is a visual example:

[image]

I realized that if I apply Bitwise OR on all the numbers from n0 to n7 it's always the correct result for n7:

```
n7 = n0 | n1 | n2 | n3 | n4 | n5 | n6 | n7;
Console.WriteLine(n7); // n7 = 236
```

Unfortunately I can't think of the right way for the rest of the bytes n6, n5, n4, n3, n2, n1, n0.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Iterate from bottom to top, looking at consecutive pairs of rows. Replace the upper one with the binary AND and the lower one with the binary OR of these two rows. Repeat until nothing moves anymore.

Comment: Alternatively iterate over columns, extract and count the 1 bits using `(n[i]>>column)&1`, then fill that number of 1 bits from the bottom into the column.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to come up with a solution that did not loop over the collection N times and I believe I've found a novel divide and conquer approach:

```
int n0_, n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_, n5_, n6_, n7_;

// Input data
int n0 = 0;
int n1 = 64;
int n2 = 8;
int n3 = 8;
int n4 = 0;
int n5 = 12;
int n6 = 224;
int n7 = 0;

//Subdivide into four groups of 2 (trivial to solve each pair)
n0_ = n0 & n1;
n1_ = n0 | n1;

n2_ = n2 & n3;
n3_ = n2 | n3;

n4_ = n4 & n5;
n5_ = n4 | n5;

n6_ = n6 & n7;
n7_ = n6 | n7;

//Merge into two groups of 4
n0 = (n0_ & n2_);
n1 = (n0_ & n3_) | (n1_ & n2_);
n2 = (n0_ | n2_) | (n1_ & n3_);
n3 = (n1_ | n3_);

n4 = (n4_ & n6_);
n5 = (n4_ & n7_) | (n5_ & n6_);
n6 = (n4_ | n6_) | (n5_ & n7_);
n7 = (n5_ | n7_);

//Merge into final answer
n0_ = (n0 & n4);
n1_ = (n0 & n5) | (n1 & n4); 
n2_ = (n0 & n6) | (n1 & n5) | (n2 & n4);
n3_ = (n0 & n7) | (n1 & n6) | (n2 & n5) | (n3 & n4);
n4_ = (n0) | (n1 & n7) | (n2 & n6) | (n3 & n5) | (n4);
n5_ = (n1) | (n2 & n7) | (n3 & n6) | (n5);
n6_ = (n2) | (n3 & n7) | (n6);
n7_ = (n3 | n7);
```

This approach requires just 56 bitwise operations, which is considerably fewer than the other solutions provided.

It is important to understand the cases in which bits will be set in the final answer. For example, a column in n5 is 1 if there are three *or more* bits set in that column. These bits can arranged in any order, which makes counting them efficiently fairly difficult.

The idea is to break the problem into sub-problems, solve the sub-problems and then merge the solutions together. Every time we merge two blocks, we know the bits will have been correctly "dropped" in each. This means *we won't have to check every possible permutation* of bits at each stage.

Although I didn't realize it until now, this is really similar to Merge Sort which capitalizes on sorted sub-arrays when merging.

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses only bitwise operators :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7;
        int n0_, n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_, n5_, n6_, n7_;

        // Input data
        n0 = 0;
        n1 = 64;
        n2 = 8;
        n3 = 8;
        n4 = 0;
        n5 = 12;
        n6 = 224;
        n7 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            n0_ = n0 & n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7;
            n1_ = (n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n0;
            n2_ = (n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n1;
            n3_ = (n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n2;
            n4_ = (n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n3;
            n5_ = (n5 & n6 & n7) | n4;
            n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
            n7_ = n7 | n6;

            n0 = n0_;
            n1 = n1_;
            n2 = n2_;
            n3 = n3_;
            n4 = n4_;
            n5 = n5_;
            n6 = n6_;
            n7 = n7_;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("n0: {0}", n0);
        Console.WriteLine("n1: {0}", n1);
        Console.WriteLine("n2: {0}", n2);
        Console.WriteLine("n3: {0}", n3);
        Console.WriteLine("n4: {0}", n4);
        Console.WriteLine("n5: {0}", n5);
        Console.WriteLine("n6: {0}", n6);
        Console.WriteLine("n7: {0}", n7);
    }
}
```

It can be simplified though, because we don't really need to recompute all numbers :
At each iteration, the top row is definitively good.

I mean this :

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7;
        int n0_, n1_, n2_, n3_, n4_, n5_, n6_, n7_;

        n0 = 0;
        n1 = 64;
        n2 = 8;
        n3 = 8;
        n4 = 0;
        n5 = 12;
        n6 = 224;
        n7 = 0;

        n0_ = n0 & n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7;
        n1_ = (n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n0;
        n2_ = (n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n1;
        n3_ = (n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n2;
        n4_ = (n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n3;
        n5_ = (n5 & n6 & n7) | n4;
        n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n0 = n0_;
        n1 = n1_;
        n2 = n2_;
        n3 = n3_;
        n4 = n4_;
        n5 = n5_;
        n6 = n6_;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n0: {0}", n0);
        n1_ = (n1 & n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n0;
        n2_ = (n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n1;
        n3_ = (n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n2;
        n4_ = (n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n3;
        n5_ = (n5 & n6 & n7) | n4;
        n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n1 = n1_;
        n2 = n2_;
        n3 = n3_;
        n4 = n4_;
        n5 = n5_;
        n6 = n6_;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n1: {0}", n1);
        n2_ = (n2 & n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n1;
        n3_ = (n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n2;
        n4_ = (n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n3;
        n5_ = (n5 & n6 & n7) | n4;
        n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n2 = n2_;
        n3 = n3_;
        n4 = n4_;
        n5 = n5_;
        n6 = n6_;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n2: {0}", n2);
        n3_ = (n3 & n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n2;
        n4_ = (n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n3;
        n5_ = (n5 & n6 & n7) | n4;
        n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n3 = n3_;
        n4 = n4_;
        n5 = n5_;
        n6 = n6_;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n3: {0}", n3);
        n4_ = (n4 & n5 & n6 & n7) | n3;
        n5_ = (n5 & n6 & n7) | n4;
        n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n4 = n4_;
        n5 = n5_;
        n6 = n6_;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n4: {0}", n4);
        n5_ = (n5 & n6 & n7) | n4;
        n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n5 = n5_;
        n6 = n6_;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n5: {0}", n5);
        n6_ = (n6 & n7) | n5;
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n6 = n6_;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n6: {0}", n6);
        n7_ = n7 | n6;
        n7 = n7_;
        Console.WriteLine("n7: {0}", n7);
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew there would be simple solution... Thank you @hoang! I like your method.

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of 1-bits in each column. Next, clear the column and add the right number of "tokens" from the bottom.

Comment: I was thinking about this option, but my knowledge is not sufficient to implement it. I mean let's say the bytes from n0 to n7 are the elements of one array. After we transform each element of the array to binary, we get this:
00000000
01000000
00001000
00001000
00000000
00001100
11100000
00000000
How can we treat the bits by columns?

Comment: I guess you have to loop over the rows and extract each column. Alternative: A very simple solution would first convert the values to a two-dimensional bool array, manipulate it and convert back. Not efficient, but maybe still the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on CodesInChaos's suggestion:

```
static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static string AsBits(this int b) {
        return Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var intArray = new[] {0, 64, 8, 8, 0, 12, 224, 0 };
        var intArray2 = (int[])intArray.Clone();
        DropDownBits(intArray2);

        for (var i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", intArray[i].AsBits(),
                intArray2[i].AsBits());
    }

    static void DropDownBits(int[] intArray) {
        var changed = true;

        while (changed) {
            changed = false;
            for (var i = intArray.Length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                var orgValue = intArray[i];
                intArray[i] = (intArray[i] | intArray[i - 1]);
                intArray[i - 1] = (orgValue & intArray[i - 1]);
                if (intArray[i] != orgValue) changed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How it works**

Let's keep it simple and start with these 3 nibbles:

```
0) 1010
1) 0101
2) 0110
```

We start at the bottom row (i = 2). By applying a bitwise or with the row above (i-1) we make sure that all bits in row 2 that are 0, will become 1 if it is a 1 in row 1. So we are letting the 1-bits in row 1 fall down to row 2.

```
1) 0101
2) 0110
```

The right bit of row 1 can fall down because there is "room" (a `0`) in row 2. So row 2 becomes row 2 or row 1: `0110 | 0101` which is `0111`.

Now we must remove the bits that have fallen down from row 1. Therefor we perform a bitwise and on the original values of row 2 and 1. So `0110 & 0101` becomes `0100`. Because the value of row 2 has changed, `changed` becomes `true`.
The result so far is as follows.

```
1) 0100
2) 0111
```

This concludes the inner loop for `i` = 2.
Then `i` becomes 1. Now we'll let the bits from row 0 fall down to row 1.

```
0) 1010
1) 0100
```

Row 1 becomes the result of row 1 or row 0: `0100 | 1010` which is `1110`. Row 0 becomes the result of a bitwise and on those two values: `0100 & 1010` is `0000`. And again, the current row has changed.

```
0) 0000
1) 1110
2) 0111
```

As you can see we aren't finished yet. That what the `while (changed)` loop is for. We start all over again at row 2.

Row 2 = `0111 | 1110 = 1111`, row 1 = `0111 & 1110 = 0110`. The row has changed, so `changed` is `true`.

```
0) 0000
1) 0110
2) 1111
```

Then `i` becomes 1. Row 1 = `0110 | 0000 = 0110`, Row 0 = `0110 & 0000 = 0000`. Row 1 hasn't changed, but the value of `changed` already is `true` and stays that way.

This round of the `while (changed)` loop, again something has changed, so we'll execute the inner loop once more.

This time, none of the rows will change, resulting in `changed` remaining `false`, in turn ending the `while (changed)` loop.

Comment: Thanks, comecme! It works fine, though too complicated for my understanding :)

Comment: I've tried to explain how it works. However, as people often say, if your code needs that much explaining, it's too complicated.

Comment: I've removed the need for casting the result to byte. First I was using `byte`. But the result of bitwise operation on two bytes is an `int`. That's why I had to use `(byte)(byteArray[i] | byteArray[i-1])`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination. Now it's clear. What I was missing before was the basic conseption: Row N = Row N | Row N-1; Row N-1 = Row N & Row N-1;